# How can I finish data stream to InputSource to parse it

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am trying to build combined SAX/DOM parser which would use SAX parser to determine blocks of data I need and forward these blocks one by one to DOM parser. 
For this I'm using XLMWriter, which writes blocks I need to InputSource using PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream:

```
public class CombinedReaderObserv {

XMLOutputFactory output = null;
XMLStreamWriter writer = null;
PipedOutputStream out;
PipedInputStream in;
InputSource inpSourse;

public CombinedReaderObserv () throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
    out = new PipedOutputStream();
    in = new PipedInputStream(out);
    inpSourse = new InputSource(in);
    output = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    writer = output.createXMLStreamWriter(out);
}

@Override
public void read(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    //Create SAX parser
    SAXParserFactory SAXfactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parser = SAXfactory.newSAXParser();
    SAXHandler handler = new SAXHandler();
    parser.parse(is, handler);
    writer.close(); 
}

private class SAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    @Override
    public void startElement(String URI,
            String localName,
            String qName,
            Attributes attributes) {
        try {
            //Enables data streaming if found Facility Site starting tag 
            //element and starts streaming data to the InputSource
            switch (qName) {
                case "FacilitySite":
                    write = true;
                    writer.writeStartDocument();
                    writer.writeStartElement("root");
                default:
                    if (write == true) {
                        writer.writeStartElement(qName);
                    }
            }
        } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String URI,
            String localName,
            String qName) {
        switch (qName) {
            //ends all XML elements and forvardsthe InputSource object  
            //to parser if found facility site element closing tag 
            case "FacilitySite":
                try {
                    writer.writeEndElement();
                    writer.writeEndElement();
                    writer.writeEndDocument();
                    reader.read(inpSourse); 
                    writer.flush();            //Program stops here
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                write = false;
                break;
            default:
                if (write == true) {
                    try {
                        writer.writeEndElement();
                    } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that after parsing the InputSource object correctly parcer Object continues to wait for more input. 
Closing XML writer before parsing doesn't lead to anything, closing piped connection leads to "pipe closed" exception.

How can I make DOM parser realise that there would be no more input?

**UPDATE**

Switch from Piped to ByteArray Streams helped.

Comment: Don't use piped streams unless you have two separate threads. Otherwise they can deadlock. They're really very little use at all.

Comment: I'll get rid of it, but when I tried to make a tread to parse the incoming block result was the same: parsing tread stoped and waited for more input.